# Make lists named as elements in another list

Tags: python

I want to make some list, each one named as an element in another list.

Input:
`["A","B","C"]`

The output that I want:

```
A = []
B = []
C = []
```

Comment: Use a dictionary for this: `lists = {name: [] for name in list_names}`

Comment: this can be done but is inadvisable.  You might prefer a dict, `d = {}; d["A"] = []` for example

Comment: Don't dynamically create variables.

Comment: *How can a create variables named THIS form THIS* It seems this question is asked about once a week

Comment: @dawg I'd say multiple times a week

Answer (score 1):

While this can be done by modifying the `vars()` dict, I would suggest just using a separate dict for that:

```
lists  = dict()
names = ["A","B","C"]

for name in names:
    lists[name] = []
```

Comment: "this can be done by modifying the `vars()` dict" in CPython, not in general